# Реализую поиск выбором на Java, метод searchIndexSmallest ищет минимальное значение и возвращает int, метод sortSearch требует переделать его boolean

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка-выбором

Реализую алгоритм поиск выбором на Java из книги Адитъя Бхаргава "Грокаем алгоритмы" (в книге пример на Python), метод **searchIndexSmallest** ищет минимальное значение и возвращает ***int***, используя его, метод **sortSearch** заполняет новый лист в порядке убывания, но у меня он требует переделать **searchIndexSmallest** из ***int*** в ***boolean***. Почему и куда копать не пойму. Прошу подсказать!

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Current {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer [] array = {7, 5, 3, 4, 9, 1, 2, 6, 8, 4, 7};
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> sortList = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(list, array);

        System.out.println(sortSearch(list, sortList));
    }

    public static int searchIndexSmallest(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        int smallest = list.get(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (smallest > i) {
                smallest = list.get(i);
            }
        }
        return smallest;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> sortSearch(ArrayList<Integer> list, ArrayList<Integer> sortList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            sortList.add(i) = searchIndexSmallest(list); // Make 'searchIndexSmallest' return 'boolean'
            list.remove(i);
        }
        return sortList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Кто этого требует? В методе searchIndexSmallest вы делаете что попало, сравнивая длинное со сладким...

Comment: а в строчке ``sortList.add(i) = searchIndexSmallest(list);`` еще  большая ерунда

Comment: Ребята, спасибо за участие, но комментарий "ерунда" незначительно указывает на проблему. Подробный разбор от Nowhere Man и подсказка MBo значительно полезнее! Согласен, использовать значение итератора, вместо значения из листа по этому итератору - ошибка глупая, даже детская, надеюсь с опытом она исчезнет. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка не в том, что [`List::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) возвращает `boolean`, а в попытке *присвоить* целочисленный результат, возвращаемый одним методом (`searchIndexSmallest`), результату другого метода:

```
 error: unexpected type
            sortList.add(i) = searchIndexSmallest(list); // Make 'searchIndexSmallest' return 'boolean'
                        ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
```

Для оператора присваивания в левой части должна быть *переменная*.

Однако алгоритм содержит и другие логические ошибки, даже если исправить предыдущую:

- в методе `searchIndexSmallest` *значение* в списке `list` сравнивается с *индексом*, поэтому результат работы этого метода неправильный
- в методе `sortSearch` размер списка `list` будет уменьшаться после вызова `list.remove`, соответственно в "отсортированном" списке будет только половина значений

Вариант исправленного кода:

```java
public static int findSmallest(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int smallest = list.get(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (smallest > list.get(i)) {
            smallest = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> sortSearch(ArrayList<Integer> list, ArrayList<Integer> sortList) {
    for (int i = 0, n = list.size(); i < n; i++) {
        Integer min = findSmallest(list);
        sortList.add(min);
        list.remove(min);
    }
    return sortList;
}
```

Важно, чтобы из исходного списка удалялось *Integer* значение, а не *int* индекс.

---

Вариант с индексами выглядит так:

```java
public static int findSmallestIndex(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int smallestIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(smallestIndex) > list.get(i)) {
            smallestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return smallestIndex;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> sortSearch(ArrayList<Integer> list, ArrayList<Integer> sortList) {
    for (int i = 0, n = list.size(); i < n; i++) {
        int minIx = findSmallestIndex(list);
        sortList.add(list.get(minIx));
        list.remove(minIx);
    }
    return sortList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод

```
sortList.add(i)
```

самодостаточен, к списку добавляется i, результат - boolean - успешно или нет.

Присваивать левой части ничего не надо. Возможно, вместо `i` вы хотели подставить результат `searchIndexSmallest`, но сначала реализуйте этот метод правильно